# magento2 layered navigation not working

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, product-collection

I have included following block in default category.
its working fine with main product collection.I mean its displaying only 2 products.but layered navigation getting all products count.

Can you help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

```
     <?php

namespace Dcw\Search\Block;

class Form extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer
     */
    protected $catalogLayer;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver, array $data = []) {
        $this->catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->apply();
    }

    public function apply() {
        $skus = array('sku1', 'sku2');
        $collection = $this->catalogLayer->getProductCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('in' => $skus));
    }

}
```